# I do not understand the statement x = points[i,0] from the given code? However when I try it with a similar data of list in lists i get an error

Tags: python, list, numpy

I saw this from an example to generate data points. The points data is a list of lists stored in an excel file. I do not understand the statement x = points[i,0], like how does it work? Furthermore, I created my own data as a list of lists but the same statement does not work?

This is what I did

```
ded = [[1, 2], [3, 2], [3, 3], [5, 1], [8, 0], [4, 7], [5, 7], [4, 6]]

for i in range(0, len(ded)):
    x = ded[i, 0]
    y = ded[i, 1]
    print(x, y)

from numpy import *
points = genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",")

for i in range(0, len(points)):
    x = points[i, 0]
    y = points[i, 1]
    print(x,y)
```

This is the format the points data is stored:

```
[[ 32.50234527  31.70700585]
 [ 53.42680403  68.77759598]
 [ 61.53035803  62.5623823 ]
 [ 47.47563963  71.54663223]
 [ 59.81320787  87.23092513]
```

Stored in a list of lists but doesn't have the comma between them.

This is what I get using my version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\omanz\Documents\python\python trials\PythonWithMosh\dictionary.py", line 57, in <module>
    x = ded[i, 0]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

This is the answer I get using the online code example:

```
32.50234526945303 31.70700584656992
53.42680403327502 68.77759598163891
61.53035802563644 62.5623822979458
47.4756396347861 71.54663223356778
59.81320786951232 87.23092513368739
55.14218841394382 78.21151827079923...
```

Answer (score 0):

`points` value has different type and this type handles tuples. Builtin python's `vector` don't handle tuples, so if you want two dimensional array, you need to use something like this:

```
ded[i][0]
```